# How does a gender detection algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, web, scripting, automation, text-analysis

How does a gender detection algorithm detect the gender of a name. For example, like on the following sites:

1. http://genderchecker.com/
2. https://gender-api.com/
3. https://genderize.io/
4. http://www.genderguesser.com/

I'm not interested in how to implement their API or data, but in how the algorithm works. How do they analyse, calculate, estimate the gender based on a textual string (firstname) and moreover how can they determine the origin country of that name and the probability of their guess?

Comment: same here... Those links just use database of names and associated genders with it. I am also interested how humans know the gender of name. i.e "Zane" which I never heard before but for me, it sounds like a unisex name. How do I know "Macey" is a female name and "Luke" a men's name. What's going on inside our head to know the gender of these names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to click on one of your links, and the first thing that loaded was them explicitly stating the algorithm...

> To guess the gender of a name we carry out a web search. We look up
>   queries like “Mr [name]”, “Mrs [name]” or “[name] and his wife”,
>   “[name] and her husband” and compare the number of hits to decide
>   whether the name is a male or a female name.

Others I'm sure are similar. If you have  500,000 people named Sam and 250,000 are male and 250,000 are female, then there's a 50% chance Sam is male and a 50% chance Sam is female.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually as simple as that they have a database full of names and their associated genders - I don't think theres any way of calculating what gender any given name is. If you take a look at the first link you provided, it states "Global names currently in the database: 102,142". When you type in a name, it essentially checks what you entered against its database and provides you with the result.